# Create factory with resolver.resolveComponentFactory fails when using directive more than once at the same page

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

When I have 1 instance of my directive at my HTML page, everything works great. But when I use the same directive at the same page more than once, I get error on the creation of the component template the directive use.

Seems like this line of code fails in creating the factory:

```
private myDirective: ComponentRef<MyComponentContainer>;
...
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponentContainer); // fails
this.myDirective= this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory); // not run at all
```

`MyComponentContainr` is just a component with simple template.

What is wrong?

The error is when I try to do something like that:

```
this.myDirective.instance.top = 10;

// EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined
```

I think the problem is when I use a service inside the directive:

```
this.MyService.dataUpdated.subscribe
      (
        (data: Dimension) => {
          this.callFunc();
        }
      )
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: while trying to change the instance of myDirective, since it is undefeined. I can see in debug the line of createComponent is being skipped for some reason

Comment: Seems weird. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: I will try. I think the problem is that my directive is using a service. When I multiplae directive, What happens with the service? Same one for all?

Comment: If you add the service to providers of the directive, each directive instance provides another service instance. If you only inject it in the constructor but provider it elsewhere (`@NgModule()`, ...), then every directive instance gets the same service instance injected.

Comment: I added the service in the constructor

Comment: Yes, the problem is with the service. I removed it from constrauctor, and added the providers with the service, but how and where I create instance of that service?

Comment: My last comment was not meant as instructions, just as explanation for what the behavior is depending on what you mean by "using a service". Where did you add the providers? Where did you have it before?

Comment: The providers where at @ngModule, removed it from there and added it to my directive. Now the service will not be singleton, is the currect?

Comment: That's correct, and there shouldn't be a reason to move the provider if you want to keep it as singleton.

Comment: I get EXCEPTION: No provider for myService. Where I create its instance? Constrcutor?

Comment: I guess you need to pass the injector to `createComponent`. Add `constructor(private injector:Injector){}` to the component that creates the component and then pass `this.injector` to `.createComponent(...)`. Look up the docs how to pass the injector. I assumed if none is passed it automatically uses the parent injector, but I guess it's worth a try.